# How do I read the accuracy stat of weapons?

Tags: planetside-2

The accuracy stats of my favorite gun read:

```
HIP ACCURACY   2 / 2.5 / 2.5 / 3 / 0.14
AIM ACCURACY   0 / 0.17 / 0 / 0.32 / 0.07
```

What exactly does each of these numbers mean? I guess the different numbers apply to different game situations like standing, running or jumping, but which one is which? I am asking because I also have a different gun which is better in some but worse in others so I would like to know how I should adjust my playstyle when using that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numbers are given in the following order:

Crouch  Still,
Crouch Move,
Stand Still,
Stand Move,
Accuracy Loss Per Shot Fired

Hovering over accuracy when looking at a weapon's stats on the official [Weapon Overview](https://www.planetside2.com/players/#!/weapon-overview) displays this information.